# how to implement a wait until prompt appears before exection of cmds?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, gnu-screen

How can I wait until a shell prompt appears before further commands get executed (in a bash script e.g?) on some hosts I can do `ssh user@host echo "test";` and it would login, and when ready execute echo "test" - but it looks like it doesn't work on every host. I would like to wait for the `#` or `$` prompt to appear before continuing on to execute `echo "test"` - how can i do so?

When I do `ssh user@host` then wait for the `#` and manually do `echo "test"` it works as you would expect. How can I put this into a script? `ssh user@host -t echo "test"` doesn't work either.

I'm particularly trying to do something like: `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 2222 user@host -t tail -f /var/log/MyFile.log` i.e. tail a log file of a host and show the result on the local shell
Instead of tailing the log file, it just throws me to the prompt:

```
No entry for terminal type "screen";
using dumb terminal settings.
#
```

`-->` Please ignore that the prompt is `root`, that's not part of this thread. And yes, it is launched out of a screen session - from a plain terminal (xterm), it says `No entry for terminal type "xterm";` (e.g.) instead.

Without `-t` I get `FATAL: not a terminal` and it throws me back to the local shell.

Comment: That'll never exit. Do you really want that?

Comment: @roaima yes I do, it will exit by `Ctrl-C` or reboot of the remote box - it's an embedded device, not a PC

Comment: On the remote machine, does the shell's startup file (probably `~/.bashrc`) do something that actually requires a terminal, like start `screen` or use some other tool that requires a terminal?

Comment: @Kusalananda it is running /bin/sh and there's no `~/.bashrc` nor is there any other file (also no `.`files) in the home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just chatted with the guy that implemented this recently! He said it's due to the fact that the shell gets funneled through some other login binary for security reasons (ability to disable root access for production builds). The solution is to change the path to the extra binary in `/etc/passwd` back to the shell binary.

Answer (score 1):

As last resort you can maybe use the program "expect".

Here is a simple example how to use expect with ssh: https://www.journaldev.com/1405/expect-script-ssh-example-tutorial